# Can I use android app on PC?

Tags: virtualbox, android, vmware-player

I use android-x86 on PC using VMware or virtualbox.
I wonder how I can install android application.
(Assume that the app is freely available from android market.)
My PC OS is Windows 7 (32bit)

Comment: Did you try these instructions: http://www.android-x86.org/documents/apphowto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try these instructions: https://web.archive.org/web/20160310001352/http://www.android-x86.org/documents/apphowto - Updated to use Archive.org link.

As of August 2020, I now use BlueStacks to run Android applications on a Windows 10 PC using Hyper-V.  [Here are the instructions to do that.](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041390952-How-to-use-BlueStacks-on-Windows-10-with-Hyper-V-enabled)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bypass android-x86, you can download and try the [BlueStacks App Player](http://bluestacks.com/app-player/) for free.  Once installed, the app player gives you access to the Android Market so you can download free apps from there.

Comment: +1 Because this looks like a cool application, but this appears to allow you to run the Android app natively on a PC or MAC.  The question however was how to install Android applications in Android-x86 running virtually using VMware of Virtualbox.  However, again, the BlueStacks App Player looks promising.  One question is how do you get the application APK file to install?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Hmm... yeah, I think I read that wrong.  I thought he was running a Windows 7 VM.  Anyway, I did try this and it gives you access to the Android App Store from within the BlueStacks App Player, so you can install free apps from there.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Your link attached to the question is probably a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Android Apps on PC/Laptop. You just need to install Android Emulator. There are lot of emulators. I would prefer Drop4x. It makes easy to use. I have been using it. Droid4x Android emulators make it easy to run Google's mobile OS side by side with Windows, so you can always access your favorite mobile messaging apps, games and more on the PCs you already own — and take advantage of your larger monitor, hardware keyboard and other peripherals. [Here](http://intechbuzz.com/download-droid4x-offline-installer-for-pc-windows-mac/) is a link of Droid4x Offline Installer For PC which is run and install app on your PC.